# Failed at the core-js@2.6.9 postinstall script when running create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post-install, core-js

I'm installing react locally, and then creating a react app. However, it fails at the postinstall script part. Following is the error:
[image]

Comment: When posting errors here, please post them in plain text. Additionally, please post the code or config that could be the cause of the error. Presently, this question does not have an [mcve].

Comment: @halfer, I'm not coding anything. I'm typing commands in cmd.exe to create a react app. The following are the commands:
1) install react
2) npx create-react-app robofriends